# Adding rounded corners to a view?

Tags: java, android

In my layout, I have two rectangular semi-transparent views in the following configuration:

```
---------------------|
|      |    B        |
|       -------------|
|  A   |         
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
--------
```

To make it look nicer, I want to round off the bottom right corner of A and add a curve in the corner where A to B meet like this:

```
---------------------|
|                    |
|        ------------|
|       /         
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|------/
```

Can anyone suggest a way I can do this, preferably without having to use bitmaps (as this means I can change the colors and corner sizes more easily later)?

I know how to round A by itself using a rectangular background drawable and clipping, but I can't think of a nice way to add the corner joining A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A and B are in a relative layout, you could add a small C view right in the corner, below and left aligned to B, and have it draw the rounding in onDraw().

edit:

in [API Demos -> Graphics -> Xfermodes](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html) there's an example of how you could draw something with a circle cut out of it (but I have no experience with that).

Comment: Thanks, but the trouble I'm having is I don't know how to draw the shape required i.e. a square with a circle cut out of the middle.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't create corners only from the properties of a view, so I guess you only have two options.

First, use a custom image (maybe a 9-patch can be helpfull to get a single background for the whole thing) but then again, you can't change the color easily.

The other would be to create your own View and override the onDraw() method (take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html))

Comment: Thanks, any hints how I can draw the shape I want with onDraw?

Comment: Here's what I think could work. You set a background color for your A and B view. then let's call C the view in the bottom rght (below B, right to A). Using the onDraw() you can call the provided Canvas method. The simplest would be to make  a full rect on the top left corner with Canvas.drawRect(), then over the rect add a circle with the background color with Canvas.drawOval().